# About correct definition of iterator_category

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14

Is this a well-defined iterator?

```
struct my_iterator
{
    struct iterator_category : std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,
                               std::output_iterator_tag
    {};

    // rest of implementation. Assume it correctly models 
    // the output and bidirectional iterator requirements.
};
```

I have read in different places that the inner `iterator_category` must be an alias (`typedef`/`using`) to one of the standard iterator category tags, but the standard exactly says (C++14/N3797):

> **[std.iterator.tags]/1** For every iterator of type Iterator, `iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category` shall be defined to be
>   the most specific category tag that describes the iterator’s behavior.

It doesn't say that must be strictly an *alias*, but that it must *be* one of them, because inheritance defines an *is-a* relationship after all.

Because in case it isn't allowed, `boost::iterator_facade` would define non-valid iterators (it uses inheritance in some cases to define a combined category/traversal tag).

In case it is allowed, shouldn't the standard impose some further requirements to `iterator_category` types, to help implementations know what can they expect about the inner type?

What if `iterator_category` is not default constructible, for example? Implementations couldn't make use of function overloading to select a best algorithm implementation, and play strictly with template specialization and `std::is_base_of` and the sort, forcing more verbose implementations.

Comment: The inheritance may not pose a problem. But the multiple inheritance will bring a rain of ambiguity onto your head. That's why the alias is recommended.

Comment: @StoryTeller Read the added comments. The problem is not about inheritance actually, the problem is `iterator_category`s would be user-defined types without requirements.

Comment: It's not allowed, but people do it anyway, so implementations try to accommodate such code.

Comment: @T.C. so we can say `boost::iterator_facade` is not standard conforming under certaing reference, value_type and category template parameter combinations.